# Why are strings passed to winston kept in memory, leaking and ultimately crashing the node.js process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, winston

I'm inspecting a heap snapshot created by [node-heapdump](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump)@0.3.14, running on Node.js 10.16.0 in Amazon Linux with kernel 4.14.123-86.109.amzn1.x86_64. Heap snapshot is 1GB and, good news, strings visibly consume most of it, using 750MB of both shallow and retained size.

Most of these strings are bound to be logged by winston (winston@3.2.1, winston-transport@4.3.0, winston-logsene@2.0.7), at a log level (`silly`) lower than my app's minimal level (`debug`). So, a few dozen times per second,

- I build a log string.
- I pass it to `winston.log` with a logLevel `silly`.
- No log happens (as expected, `silly` < `debug`).

**Expected**: strings are GCed and life goes on.

**Actual**: strings accumulate in memory, are not GCed, node OOMs at max-heap-size (1.4GB).

---

I am positive strings *do* leak. What I'm describing is *not* nominal operation between two normal GCs because, looking at the contents of the strings in the snapshot, I see a great deal of variation that, in the case of my app, can only come from hours of running.

Also, the devtools sometimes report *huge* sizes for these strings (23MB for a string that is actually 1KB), and the retainers tree is humongous, with >18000 levels of a `next` method inside objects `message` and `chunk` (see screenshot below).

So, my two questions are:

1. **Why does winston keep these strings in memory?** An idea I had: maybe winston keeps the messages in a queue/buffer, doesn't log because the level is too low, and never flushes the queue?
2. **What's going on in this heapsnapshot?** How can my little 1KB string have a shallow/retained size of 23MB?! What's going on in this crazy retainers tree / any idea who these `next` / `message` / `chunk` objects belong to?

Available to provide additional information. Thank you!

[image: winston string in node heapsnapshot with crazy size & retainers]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm seeing the same thing in my app right now.

Comment: @AndrewBurgess no actual solution on the winston side, but I worked around the issue in my winston bindings/wrapper. Super simple: if the level of the line being logged is lower than my app's logging level, I early return. It worked, the memory leak is solved. I don't know why winston doesn't do the same. Leaving this open because I'm still curious about why not and about the heap insanity .

Comment: @RonanJouchet Today I run into the same case: heap is constantly growing with Winston logs and I see identical *next* tree in memory analysis. However I am logging quite a lot of data, so maybe different logger would be able to handle it.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue. I think this is a relevant issue: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1871

Comment: how about enabling the log rotation?

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Winston related to how it used streams. It was fixed in a pull request, you can read more about the issue and the fix here:
https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1871